# How to properly create mysql2 connection with error handling in a separate file

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I've trying to achieve the following connection method with node.js and [mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/) but something is missing and i've getting various errors (mostly `db.query is not a function`).

The keys are the following:

- reuse the already created connection
- error handling
- auto reconnect if connection failed

ORIGINAL (check update below):

```
//dbConnection.js

const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const dbConfig = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    database: 'db',
    password: 'pass'
};

var connection;

//Exporting to use it elsewhere
module.exports = async function connect() { 
    if (connection){
        //so if the connection is already exists use it again
        return connection;
    }
    try {
        connection = await mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);    
        console.info("Connected to MySql on '" + db_config.host + "'");
        return connection;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error when connecting to MySql:', error);
        // auto retry in 5 seconds
        setTimeout(connect, 5000);
    }
}
```

```
//dbRoutes.js

const db = require('./dbConnection.js');

dbRouter.get('/get_user', async (req, res, /* next */) => {
    const userId = req.userId;
    await db.query(
        `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${userId};`,
        (err, result) => {
            return res.status(200).send({
                msg: 'success',
                user: result
            });
        }
    );
});
```

UPDATE:

I'm able to make it work but i'm not sure that this is the best way so i'm ask for any enhancements that come in your minds.

```js
//dbConnection.js

const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const db_config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'bln',
    password: ''
};

var connection;
const connect = async function () { 
    if (connection){
        return connection;
    }

    try {
        connection = await mysql.createConnection(db_config);
        console.info("Connected to MySql on '" + db_config.host + "'");
        return connection;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error when connecting to db:', error);
        connection = undefined;
        setTimeout(connect, 5000);
    }
}

module.exports = connect;
```

```js
//dbRoutes.js

const dbc = require('./dbConnection.js');

dbRouter.post('/login', userMiddleware.validateLogin, async (req, res) => {
    const db = await dbc();
    const [results] = await db.execute(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?;`, [req.body.email]);
  return res.status(401).send({
        msg: 'success',
    user: result
    });
});
```

Comment: `module.exports = async ...` means you return a promise which means `const db = require...` will be a promise object rather than the resolved promise.

Comment: Thanks, I've deleted it also the await, but unfortunately this was not the main problem.

Comment: I agree. The main problem here is I think a misunderstanding how async code works in JS. You can't just remove the `async` keyword. The premise of your code above is wrong.

Comment: I understand it just not using it with confidence yet.

Answer (score 0):

As told in earlier posts, we are getting a promise object rather than the connection itself. So simply obtain the resolved value of the promise using the .then() method in your secondary file.

```
const connectPromise = require('./dbConnection.js');
let db;
connectPromise.then(c => {
  db = c;
});
```

Now we can work with db.query

Comment: where is the error handling here?